# Arduino Leonardo programmer not in sync

Tags: arduino

I uploaded code to an Arduino Leonardo, using the Arduino IDE, but at some point it stopped uploading, leaving this error message:

```
Guessing serial port ... /dev/ttyACM0

Connecting to programmer: .avrdude: butterfly_recv(): programmer is not responding

Found programmer: Id = "�GPRS I"; type =  
    Software Version = G.P; Hardware Version = R.S
avrdude: error: buffered memory access not supported. Maybe it isn't
a butterfly/AVR109 but a AVR910 device?
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override this check.

avrdude: error: programmer did not respond to command: leave prog mode
avrdude: error: programmer did not respond to command: exit bootloader

avrdude done. Thank you.
```

Why is this happening? How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem. Problem in my case was that I had selected a wrong board in Arduino IDE. You can easily check it here:

[image: Arduino IDE - Selecting board]